# Why is there no $\hbar \omega$ for the measured energy in this question?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

We assume a particle in a parabolic quantum well.   The 
wavefunction at $t=0$ is given by  $\Psi(x,t=0)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}\phi_0(x)+\sqrt{\frac{4}{5}}\phi_3(x)$.

We measure its energy $E$ at time $t$. The value we get for $E$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{7}{2}$, but nothing else.

May I ask you why $E$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{7}{2}$, and not $\frac{\hbar \omega}{2}$ or $\frac{7 \hbar \omega}{2}$. Isn't $E=(n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar \omega$ where $n=0,3$?

Comment: Maybe $\hbar\omega=1$? What's the hamiltonian?

Comment: Who said these are the energies?

Comment: @Othin I don't know. What I posted in my question is the only information I have

Comment: To echo @Othin, $\omega$ is a property of the particular system. The person who set the problem simply assumed a system where the product $\hbar \omega$ came out to nice numbers (in  whatever units are in use). They didn't give you the details because *they are unnecessary to the question*; you can find the answer without knowing anything not given explcitly (and approaches that rely on things not given explcitly are longer and harder).

Comment: @AaronStevens I don't really understand. What could it be else ?

Comment: @dmckee So they simply "ignored" $\hbar \omega$, is that what you mean ?

Comment: Where are you getting the $1/2$ and $7/2$ from?

Comment: That's written in the solutions I got. There are no more explanations given. I litteraly wrote down the same text as the one given in the solutions.

Comment: Then @dmckee is correct here. They are assuming $\omega=1/\hbar$ (with consistent units, of course). Or they made a mistake. Or they are asking about energy in units of $\hbar\omega$

Comment: @AaronStevens Ah okay. I find it just strange that they could not communicate it to us in a clearer manner.

Comment: @dmckee Could you eventualy post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it and the question doesn't show up in the unanswered section anymore ?

Comment: You haven't provided enough info to answer the question.  You really need to show the Hamiltonian operator expressed in some basis and how it acts on the states.  For a SHO using annihilation and creation operators the appropriate scale factors are there.  It looks like you are assuming H ~ N, or N+1/2 only using the number operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy can have many different units e.g. joules and electron volts are commonly used. We tend to choose whatever units are convenient for our calculation.

In this case the energy units being used are units of $\hbar\omega$ (or equivalently $h\nu$) so the ground state energy is $\tfrac12$, the first excited state is $\tfrac32$, the second excited state $\tfrac52$ and so on. If you wanted to convert to joules you would have to multiply by $\hbar\omega$.

Just wait until you start studying general relativity. In GR [we set all the units to unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system)!